# Is there a construct similar to ifelse() which returns all the elements and not only the first one?

Tags: r, if-statement

In the following example, how can `i.want.them.all` get all the 10 numbers from 5 to 14?

```
control.me <- 0 # or 1
a.lot.of.elements <- c(5:14)
i.want.them.all <- ifelse(control.me == 1, a.lot.of.elements, a.lot.of.elements - 10)
print(i.want.them.all)
[1] 5
```

Is there a construct that works like this? :

```
a.lot.of.elements <- c(5:14)
i.want.them.now <- magic.construct(control.me == 1, a.lot.of.elements, a.lot.of.elements - 10)
print(i.want.them.now)
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

If not, how could I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: If your condition results in a `length == 1` "logical", you could use a simple `if(test) yes else no`. `?ifelse` states that "test" determines most attributes (including `length`) of the output

Comment: You should probably read `help(ifelse)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just testing `seq_along` since any positive integer will always evaluate to TRUE:

```
> i.want.them.now <- ifelse(seq_along(a.lot.of.elements), a.lot.of.elements, character())
> i.want.them.now 
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Comment: sorry, i updated my question. there should be a control structure as the first argument of ifelse()

Comment: `ifelse` is a function returning values of the same length as its first argument ...  while `if` is a control construct (although also a function). There was a comment (since deleted) suggesting you could use `if(control.me==1){a.lot.of.elements}` . (You will not get very far suggesting modifications to `ifelse`.)